# PFObject saveEventually doesn't work under Swift

Tags: parse-platform

I don't quite understand why the Swift compiler doesn't like me calling the nullary method `saveEventually` on `PFObject`. It's normally invoked in Objective-C like this:

```
PFObject *object = [PFUser currentUser];
[object saveEventually];
```

And the Swift version is this:

```
let object = PFUser.currentUser()
object.saveEventually()
```

Swift doesn't like it! Why?

Answer (score 1):

`PFUser.currentUser()` will return nil if the user is not logged in.

You can force unwrap the object like so

```
PFUser.currentUser()!.saveEventually()
```

or better yet, wrap it around a conditional to be safe

```
if let currentUser = PFUser.currentUser() {
    currentUser.saveEventually()
}
```